# structuremap get instance of generic type based on instance

Tags: generics, structuremap

Suppose you have a variable containing an entity instance

object entity // can be a Person, Organisation, ...

And you have the classic IRepository, IRepository, ...
inheriting from IGenericRepository, IGenericRepository

How would you create an instance of IRepository for the entity object with as little (or no) reflection as possible ?

Something like :

```
var repo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance( GetGenericRepositoryInterfaceFor(entity) );
```

or

```
var repo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance( IGenericRepository<>, entity );
```

I should be able to call a method defined on IGenericRepository

```
repo.DoSometing(entity);
```

Comment: I think some information is missing from your question because your formatting is incorrect. Please correct that to make your problem comprehensible.

Comment: To be more specific, DbContext has a method ValidateEntry which can be used for custom complex validation. However, putting all custom complex validation into single method, would be violation of SRP and make the method to complex. Therefore I would like to instantiate a repository or validation service specific for that entity and perform validation there where it belongs. I don't want to put it in   the entity model, because it doesn't belong there either (e.g. the validation logic may access the database further for validation purposes)

Comment: Your question is still incomprehensible. What do you mean by "the classic IRepository, IRepository, ... inheriting from IGenericRepository, IGenericRepository"?

Comment: There is a IGenericRepository<TEntity> implemented by GenericRepository<TEntity>. 

For specific repositories e.g. PersonRespository implements IPersonRespository inheriting from IGenericRepository<Person>